# Why isn't this systemd unit file working?

Tags: systemd

Originally I had this script running on Ubuntu, thrown basically into rc.local

```
#!/bin/bash

IBSYSDIR="/home/matthewh/tmp"
hca_id=1
if [ -d ${IBSYSDIR} ]; then
  for hca in ${IBSYSDIR}/*; do
    if [ -e ${hca}/node_desc ]; then
      echo -n "$(hostname -s) HCA-${hca_id}" >> ${hca}/node_desc
    fi
    hca_id=$((hca_id+1))
  done
fi
```

Now my infrastructure is CoreOS and I'd like to reinstate this script to set the Infiniband host names for all nodes.

Ideally, to save administration overhead I'd like to just plonk a single service file into cloud-init one time and start it.  So I came up with thee systemd service file shown below.  In coming up with the single file wonder, I managed to shorten the command to a single line in the original file script.

```
[ -d ${IBSYSDIR} ] && for hca in ${IBSYSDIR}/*; do [ -e ${hca}/node_desc ] && echo -n "$(hostname -s) HCA-${hca_id}" >> ${hca}/node_desc; done
```

However, I can't seem to run `/bin/sh -c "[ -d ${IBSYSDIR} ] && for hca in ${IBSYSDIR}/*; do [ -e ${hca}/node_desc ] && echo -n "$(hostname -s) HCA-${hca_id}" >> ${hca}/node_desc; done"`

Maybe it's not pulling the environment correctly into sh.  How do I get this to work within just a single service file (no other dependant scripts)?

The service file and actual error follow.

```
[Unit]
Description=Set the infiniband hostname

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment="IBSYSDIR=/sys/class/infiniband"
Environment="hca_id=1"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "[ -d ${IBSYSDIR} ] && for hca in ${IBSYSDIR}/*; do [ -e ${hca}/node_desc ] && echo -n "$(hostname -s) HCA-${hca_id}" >> ${hca}/node_desc; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The actual error I'm seeing:

```
Sep 10 00:30:21 service2-2 systemd[1]: Starting Set the infiniband hostname...
Sep 10 00:30:21 service2-2 sh[11134]: -s): -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
Sep 10 00:30:21 service2-2 sh[11134]: -s): -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

---

So I got a little further, but it still doesn't work.

```
[Unit]
Description=Set the infiniband hostname
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'IBSYSDIR=/sys/class/infiniband && hca_id=1 && [ -d ${IBSYSDIR} ] && for hca in ${IBSYSDIR}/*; do [ -e ${hca}/node_desc ] && echo -n "$(hostname -s) HCA-${hca_id}" >> "${hca}/node_desc"; done'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But if I directly run

```
sudo /bin/bash -c 'IBSYSDIR=/sys/class/infiniband && hca_id=1 && [ -d ${IBSYSDIR} ] && for hca in ${IBSYSDIR}/*; do [ -e ${hca}/node_desc ] && echo -n "$(hostname -s) HCA-${hca_id}" >> "${hca}/node_desc"; done'
```

It does work.  What's special about the service file?  The error code returned is 1.  I presume it's a permission denied error or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change all the `$` to `$$`.

From the systemd.unit documentation:

> To pass a literal dollar sign, use "$$". Variables whose value is not known at expansion time are treated as empty strings. Note that the first argument (i.e. the program to execute) may not be a variable.

Comment: Thanks! that did it.  Along with the single quotes around the -c arg instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, systemd does not like having complex commands in its `ExecStart` directives.

Try putting your script into a wrapper file and running that from `ExecStart`.

Comment: That of course works, but it's a pain to manage.  Geez systemd is aweful.

Comment: I really hated it at first too, but I'll admit that once you come to terms with some of its "shortcomings", it's actually a way better system. I quite like not having to write long tedious init scripts for everything; now you just figure out your command (wrapped if needed), write a 5-line unit file and you're all set.

Comment: Yes and no. Binary logging... what were they thinking?  anyway.. I'm going to figure this out one way or another